# Running cmd with spaces from java

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I want to run a command through java session. The command contains spaces. as
`"C:\With Space\sample.exe"` -command_option `"C:\Source File\test.c"`
This works if

```
C:\WithoutSpace\sample.exe -command_option "C:\Source File\test.c"
```

if we keep the quotes in `C:\With Space\sample.exe` we get error as :'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.' and if we remove the quotes then the exe do not run...
please guide.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are using `Runtime#exec()`, you should try `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to run the command ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String[] arg = {"cmd","/c","C:/Source File/test.c"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(arg);
Process pr = pb.start();
```

Also, you can use `Runtime.exec(String[])` version

Example:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] args = { "cmd", "/c", "C:/Source File/test.c"};
try
{
    Process proc = rt.exec(processCommand);
}
```

Comment: +1 For using `ProcessBuilder`. Note that the code sample doesn't work because `\S` isn't a valid escape sequence :-)

Comment: "c:/source file/test.c" or "c:\\source file\\test.c"

Comment: @user93353 c:/source file/test.c

Comment: I was not asking a question - i was saying that your original paths won't work - and you can use either of the paths in my comment - both should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("'C:\WithoutSpace\sample.exe' -command_option 'C:\Source File\test.c'");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    //line contain command output
}
```